# How to check if an item is in an Array

Tags: java

I'm writing a method where it take an array, checks to see if the negative value of an element in the array is present, if it is, then it returns both the value(positive and negative).

I'm coming from python, where you can use `if i is in n`, but I don't see any similar methods with Jave. I've read around and saw there are more than one method, but they require over 6+ lines of code.. I was wondering if there was a shorter way for something this simple?

My planned algorithm is to take i in a(the array),
multiply `i*-1 = x`.
 **if x is in the array, then it adds it to an `Arraylist` that returns at the end of the for loop**

Comment: if i is in n (lookup i in array n?) --> can't be done directly apart from looping.. however you could do Arrays.asList(n).contains(i)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Arrays.binarySearch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20java.lang.Object%29) method ([Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) an calass with help methods to work with array)

Important: Array must bu sorted before using this method! It could be done by `Arrays.sort(yourArray)`

So your code will look like this

```
int index = Arrays.binarySearch(inArray, valueToFind)
//do smth with index or get item by index
```

Hope this will help you...

Comment: The array must be sorted before using `binarySearch`, which can be done using `Arrays.sort`.

Comment: Thanks, forgot to mention that..

Answer (score 1):

To find an element in the array:

```
Arrays.asList(myArray).contains(myElement);
```

Note that this will only work for non-primitive arrays. For primitives, you are better off using a `for-each` loop:

```
int myElement = 12;
for(int myArrayElement : myArray) {
    if(myElement == myArrayElement) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

---

And to reverse an integer to become negative:

```
int myElement = 123;
myElement = -myElement; // it is now -123
```

Comment: so I tried doing `Arrays.asList(a).contains(i){ .. }
and it doesnt work

Comment: Sorry, should've realised you'd be using primitives. I updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

Java has support for a kind of `foreach`: http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/flow/loops/foreach.html

```
for (type var : arr) {
    body-of-loop, use 'var' for element
}
```

Also, arrays have an index, you could use:

```
int i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   body-of-loop, use array[i] for element
}
```